# Retrieve values from database and launch a new activity when listview item is clicked

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I created a listview using an adapter. The list view contains elements retrieved from a SQLite database using a distinct query. 
When the listview item is clicked, it should retrieve all items which have that value used to do the distinct query.
My query looks like this:

```
@Override
public List<Registro> distinctByCol3(){
    List aux = new ArrayList();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true,Registro.TABLE_NAME,new String[]{
            BaseColumns._ID,
            RegistroColumns.Col1,
            RegistroColumns.Col2,
            RegistroColumns.Col3,
    },null,null,RegistroColumnas.Col3,null,null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        do {
            Registro registro = this.parseCursorToR(cursor);
            if (registro != null)
                aux.add(registro);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;
    if(!cursor.isClosed()){
        cursor.close();
    }
    return aux;
}
```

The java class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_registros);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRegistros);

    DataManager servicio = new DataManagerImpl(this);
    List<Registro> listRM = service.getRegistroDistinctedByCol3();

    final ArrayAdapter<Registro> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listRM);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After click in the element, I need to launch a new activity and show all the elements whit COL3, which is the value I used in my query.
How can I achieved my goal?
If some clarification is needed, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Add `onItemClickListener` to ListView and from `onItemClick` method start new Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yes, but how can I extract the value of COL3 to retrieve all the values?

Comment: Which all values want to retrieve?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK It is explained in the question.

Comment: Can you please explain "When the listview item is clicked, it should retrieve all items which have that value used to do the distinct query" - what do you mean by THAT VALUE..? Thanks!